# ASP.NET MVC 3.0 Routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have Controller Blog

I have Action `Index()` and `Show(stirng id)`

`Index()` displaying all posts and `Show(sting id)` displaying single post

I want to map `Blog/Show/id` to responce on `Blog/id`

So i went to Global.asxc and did that:

```
routes.MapRouteLowercase(
                "Blog", 
                "Blog/{id}", 
                new { controller = "Blog", action = "Show", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

But it is seams not to be worked, may be some one may help?

Answer (score 1):

You could have the following routes:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Blog", 
        "Blog/{id}", 
        new { controller = "Blog", action = "Show" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Blog", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Now:

- `/Blog/123` will map to `BlogController/Show(123)` action
- `/` and `/Blog` will map to `BlogController/Index` action

Comment: I already have `default` route `routes.MapRouteLowercase(             Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } );`

Comment: @jason, in the correct order? Then everything should work. What is this `MapRouteLowercase`? It is not ASP.NET MVC standard. Something you have written? Given its name I suspect that it requires all your routes to be lowercase, so you cannot have `Blog/id`, you might need `blog/id`.

Comment: i did some changes and i post another question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7283622/asp-net-mvc-3-0-routing-behaviour may be you may have look, i decided not to use Show() action but get some troubles

Comment: @jason, so maybe you could delete this question if it no longer applies or accept some answer if it helped you solve the original issue.

Answer (score 0):

The new route that you want to create should be the first one registered, otherwise the default routing will kick in and process the request.

Ensure that

```
routes.MapRouteLowercase(
                "Blog", 
                "Blog/{id}", 
                new { controller = "Blog", action = "Show", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

is placed before

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

in Global.asax RegisterRoutes